# Qt 5.11.3 - QML - treeView - resize row height depending of itemDelegate property

Tags: qt, qml, treeview

I'm trying to adapt the row height of a TreeView to automatically fit the content in its itemDelegate, but I have no clue how to do so.

So far, I tried to create a property "lines" in my itemDelegate object, but everytime I try to access it QML says my treeDeleg item is undefined.

Is there a way to get the result I want ?

EDIT : following what JarMan said, it's not possible to reference a delegateComponent by ID. So instead, is there's a way to automatically adapt the row height to its content ? Something along the lines of "height: auto" in CSS. This is really important because long values make my interface hard to read.

If all else fails, would there be a better component to create a tree styled view able to contain long, editable values ?

**main.qml :**

```
TreeView 
{

    id:treeView
    anchors.top:  rowInfo.bottom
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    itemDelegate: TreeDelegate
    {
        id: treeDeleg
    }
    style: TreeViewStyle
    {
        id: styleTree
        
        rowDelegate:Rectangle
        {
            id : rowDeleg
            height: styleData.selected ? 75 : 25 * treeDeleg.lines
            color:
            {
                var baseColor = styleData.alternate ? "white" : "#d9edf7" 
                return styleData.selected ? "yellow" : baseColor
            }
        }


    }


    Component.onCompleted:
    {
         treeView.model = Qt.binding(function()
         {
             if (typeof theModel !== "undefined")
             {
                 return theModel;

             }
             else
             {
                return null;
             }
         });
    }
    TableViewColumn
    {
        id:column1
        role: "Name"
        title: "Name"
        width: 450
    }
    TableViewColumn
    {
        id:column3
        role: "Value"
        title: "Value"
        width: 400
    }
    TableViewColumn
    {
        id:column4
        role: "Desc"
        title: "Description"
        width: 750
    }
}
```

**TreeDelegate.qml**

````
Item
{
    id: item
    width : parent.width
    height : 25
    property var lines: null

    

    TextEdit
    {
        id: text1
        font.pixelSize: 14
        readOnly: true
        focus: false
        width : parent.width
        height: 25 * lineCount
        anchors.left: parent.left
        wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap
        text: (styleData.value !== null) ? (styleData.value.text + styleData.value.id) : "";
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            lines = text1.lineCount == 0 ? 1 : text1.lineCount;
            console.log("Lines : " + lines);
        }

    }
}
```
````

Comment: You can't reference a delegate component by id. It's not an instance of the component.

Comment: Is there a way to link the rowdelegate of the styleview and the elements of the itemdelegate then ? Or better : is there a way to automatically fit the row height to the content of the row ?

Comment: There is a component named [FontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html) you can determine the preferred height of your delegate based on width of the text inside and then expand the row or elide the text.